# Retrieving Class Object from NSArray and adding to self

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, nsmutablearray, nsarray

Hi im trying to retrieve an object of a specific class from an NSMutableArray, and then add it to self: eg:

```
- (void) init{
     _Objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     Psychicing *psy = [[Psychicing alloc]init];
     [psy startPsychic];
     [_Objects addObject: psy];
     [psy release];
}
```

This creates an object of class Psychicing, then runs the [psy startPsychic] method to create the internals of the class object. Then I add the psy object to _Objects NSMutableArray.

```
-(void)startPsychic{
      id psychicParticle = [CCParticleSystemQuad ......]; //is Synthesised with (assign)
      //Other things are set here such as position, gravity, speed etc...
}
```

When a touch is detected on screen, I want to take the psy object from the _Objects array and add it to self: Something like this (Although this gives runtime error)

```
-(void) Touches.....{

     for (Psychicing *psy in _Objects){
          [self addChild: psy.psychicParticle];
     }
}
```

I hope i have explained it clearly enough, if you need more clarification let me know.
So basically:
[MainClass Init] -> [Psychicing startPsychic] -> [MainClass add to array] -> [MainClass add to self]

Comment: Please post the exact error that you are getting.

Comment: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program recieved signal SIGABRT

Comment: The code listed above will not compile because the `_Objects` variable referenced in your `Touches....` method is undeclared (it is only declared locally in `init`). I'm assuming that `_Objects` is an instance variable in your actual code - can you give us a real excerpt?

Comment: Im sorry, thats my mistake, its a global variable, not a method variable, ill update my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the _Objects (which should be a lowercase o to follow conventions) is storing objects other than the Psychicing object and you're trying to pull just the Psychicing object out of it in the -(void)Touches... method (which also should be lowercase).  If so, you could do:

```
for (id obj in _Objects)
{
  if ([obj isMemberOfClass:[Psychicing class]])
    [self addChild:obj.psychicParticle];
}
```

That will cause only the Psychicing objects in the array to be added as a child to self.

It looks like you do have another error though if the code you pasted in is your real code.  Init should be defined as:

```
- (void) init{
     _Objects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
     Psychicing *psy = [[Psychicing alloc]init];
     [psy startPsychic];
     [_Objects addObject: psy];
     [psy release];
}
```

with _Objects defined as an instance variable (or property) in the class's interface.  As you wrote it, it's a method variable in the init method and is leaking.  So when you try to access _Objects in -touches, _Objects is most likely nil.

Comment: Hey, sorry, _Objects is a global variable not a method variable. Using your code, im now having trouble with this line:
[self addChild:obj.psychicParticle]; it seems that obj doesnt have any properties named psychicParticle, so it gives me a syntax error..

Comment: Does Psychicing have a psychicParticle property?  I did that only because it's what you were storing with addChild: in the question. If you're trying to store the Psychicing object, just do [self addChild:obj];

Answer (score 0):

Okay, with the help of McCygnus I got it working, the only thing missing with a pointer to the id object:

```
 for (id obj in _Objects){
        if ([obj isMemberOfClass:[Psychicing class]]){
            Psychicing *apsy = obj;
            [apsy.psychicParticle setPosition:location];
            [self addChild:apsy.psychicParticle];
        }

    }
```