# How to use NSArray Class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsarray

I want to create an `Objective-C Class` of type `NSArray` but i dont know how to initialize it or how to add data in.

I did the following:

1- Create a new File

[image]

2-I had chosen `Objective-C Class`[image]

3-I had chosen a `Subclass of` of type `NSArray` [image]

Two Files Appear:

.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface ArrayClass : NSArray

@end
```

.m

```
#import "ArrayClass.h"

@implementation ArrayClass

@end
```

My question is: What is the next steps.

1- what methods to call in this class.

2- how to initialize the array.

3- is `-(id)init` Enough for it

**EDIT:**
i have a parser in my `ViewController` and i need to initialize another one with a different XML link, so thats why i need to have a new class with a `NSArray` type

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5752443/retrieving-class-object-from-nsarray-and-adding-to-self and https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Are you sure you want an actual *subclass* of NSArray and not just an *instance*?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve ? You will add methods according to your needs. You initialize the array in the normal way you initialize objects. The only reason to implement -(id)init is if you want to override its behaviour(remember, -(id)init is inherited from the parent class).

Comment: what you want to do by creating a class of NSArray?

Comment: Have you considered actually reading the documentation?  (And also maybe you should study up on the distinction between "class" and "instance".)

Comment: Why do you want make a subclass of nsarray? If you want to add some more features to nsarray you can do this by making a category or extension of nsarray.

Comment: @DrummerB yes im sure, see the edit

Comment: @Mutawe your added explanation explains nothing.

Comment: In 4 years of professional objective-c development I subclassed NSArray exactly once — and only as a [sample code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8198852/106435). So if you think, you need to subclass it and there is no other way, you are on the wrong track.

Comment: Please learn more about programming before you attempt working with Objective-C again.  You need to understand the fundamentals.

Comment: The OP himself voted to close. And since then no edit was performed. So whoever is voting to reopen: please explain your motivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to just post this so that it's stated by someone.

NSArray is a class cluster, a wrapper around an internal implementation. The internal details of it change depending on the content and size of the array so that it's optimized for performance. As a result of this it is not a good idea to subclass NSArray (or NSDictionary).

I suppose you could extend the class by adding a category on it, this is a better and more 'Cocoa' way to add functionality. There are some guides in Apple developer docs on design patterns which give assistance on this.

Maybe restate the question so we are all clear as we are confused as to whether you do actually want to subclass it or just create one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're simply trying to use an `NSArray` just do this:

```
NSArray  *myArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"foo",@"bar",@"baz",nil];
```

No need to do what you're doing unless you want to change the actual structure and extend `NSArray`.

Comment: i have a parser in my ViewController and i need to initialize another one with a different XML link, so thats why i need to have a new class with a NSArray type

Comment: Hey Mutawe. I appreciate the clarification. Sadly it doesn't explain quite clearly enough of us to help you :) You say you have a parser in your view controller ( I presume to parse XML ) and you need to create another one to parse some different XML. Could you post the line of code that creates the original parser perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8964624/1219956) if you are really trying to extend `NSArray`

if you are not intending to extend the functionality of an NSArray, you are probably looking to create and instance of NSArray, which is as simple as going `NSArray *arrayName = [[NSArray alloc] init]` within some area where you need an array,

Comment: This is wrong. All NSArray subclasses must implement functionality as specified in the NSArray class reference.

Comment: oh i see, i was under the assumption it was like any other object. ill change my answer

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want an array you can add data to dynamically you are going to want

```
NSMutableArray *arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

It all depends what you want.